# Postgres : How to group status for user in date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres as database. 
**Problem statement:** 
Once User is create into system, its status [added, removed] is maintained in user_status table.
User status are stored historically i.e. per day one record with user status.
**Objective:** Find user status for selected date range where 
If user is not created into system for selected date range then status 'NA'
If user is added into system for selected date range then status 'Added'
If user is removed from system for selected date range then status 'Removed'
If user is different status in system for selected date range then status 'Multiple'.
Note: user can be added and removed multiple times.

**User** table

| user_id | user_added_dt |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-04-11 |
| 67890 | 2021-04-18 |

**USER_STATUS** table

| user_id | date | status | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-04-11 | Added |  |
| 12345 | 2021-04-12 | Added |  |
| 12345 | 2021-04-13 | Added |  |
| 12345 | 2021-04-14 | Removed | removal reason 1 |
| 12345 | 2021-04-15 | Removed | removal reason 1 |
| 12345 | 2021-04-16 | Removed | removal reason 1 |
| 12345 | 2021-04-17 | Added |  |
| 12345 | 2021-04-18 | Added |  |
| 67890 | 2021-04-18 | Added |  |

**Output expected**
Example 1 
Date range : from = '2021-04-01' and to = '2021-04-05' 
Output :

| user_id | status | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | NA | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-05 |
| 67890 | NA | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-05 |

Example 2 
Date range : from = '2021-04-11' and to = '2021-04-13' 
Output :

| user_id | status | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Added | 2021-04-11 | 2021-04-13 |
| 67890 | NA | 2021-04-11 | 2021-04-13 |

Example 3 
Date range : from = '2021-04-05' and to = '2021-04-16' 
Output :

| user_id | status | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Multiple | 2021-04-05 | 2021-04-16 |
| 67890 | NA | 2021-04-05 | 2021-04-16 |

Example 4 
Date range : from = '2021-04-12' and to = '2021-04-15' 
Output :

| user_id | status | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Multiple | 2021-04-12 | 2021-04-15 |
| 67890 | NA | 2021-04-12 | 2021-04-15 |

I have tried to do user_status outer join with date_range but it did not go in direction to solve the issue.
Please guide in solving this problem.

Comment: I tried some things, but it did not help you... sorry.... 

Answer (score 0):

Try to break the desirable result in parts.

range of date:
where date_column between '2021-04-11' and  '2021-04-12'

Second. change the status return. use some conditional to that.

Take a look at Coalesce, or other conditional.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-conditional.html

The distinct, could help to return just 1 return per status+id.

if necessary concatenate strings to obtain some diferent results, and segregate your select.